# awk if/else conditions and printing last line

Tags: awk

My two example files looks like this:

F1

```
Red -
Blue -
Green -
```

F2

```
Yellow +
Pink +
ColorX +
```

I need awk script to print first/last line depending on `$2 Field` (If `$2 == "+"` -- print first line; `else` -- print last line).

I managed to write awk script that prints first line, but how can I add `else` in order to print last line?

```
awk '{if (NR == 1 && $2 == "+") print}' F2
Yellow +
```

How can I modify this code to input `F1` and get `Green -` printed?

Maybe it is possible to add something like this: `awk '{if (NR == 1 && $2 == "+") print ; else {END print} }'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 && $2 == "+" { print ; p=1 ; exit } 
     END { if (p != 1) { print $0 } }' INPUTFILE
```

Note: this assumes, that if the first line does not contains `'+'` the last line must get printed.

Answer (score 2):

Short hacky awk

```
awk 'NR==($2=="+"){exit}END{print}' file
```

This will print the first line if it contains `+` or the last line

Answer (score 1):

To print the last line, you can just store it to a variable each time, then print the last value when the file processing ends. There is a special pattern/condition `END` you can use for this.

```
($2 == "-") { line = $0                  }
END         { if (line != "") print line }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using an END block:

```
awk 'NR == 1 && $2 == "+" {print $0;} {l=$0;f=$2;} END{if (f == "-"){print l;}}' F1
```

We keep the condition `NR == 1 && $2 == "+"` but in the pattern block (`AWK` style) instead of using an if statement.

Then you can add another block that keeps the whole line (l variable) and the second field (f variable) overwriting each variable every new line. So, in the END block you will have the whole line of the last line in `l` and the second filed of the last line in `f`. Then you can print `l` depending on the value of `f`.